# Dropdown not displaying selected marked value in HTML, while clicking browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In HTML, lets say in first page i have a `drop-down`. When user selects value from `Dropdown` and clicking on `Save` button then it persists the info in DB and we will be taken to next `section/page`. Now, if user click on `Back` button in browser then the previously selected value is not selected (instead it shows the first value from `dropdown`) in UI, if reloaded then able to get the proper value in dropdown.

While checking the network log for response, in that HTML selected is marked properly.

```
<select id="city">
    <option value="">- Select -</option>
    <option value="C">Chennai</option>
    <option value="B" selected="selected">Bangalore</option>
    <option value="D">Delhi</option>
</select>
```

for the first time, its properly showing properly as "Bangalore", while loading from browser back button, its showing "- Select -", for the same html response above.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Please share a code snippet and clarify the question in a more specific way.

Comment: drop-down selected marked value is not displaying in chrome browser(specifically in mobile view), while clicking back button in browser

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly then I think you want to keep the user selected `value` in a `dropdown` when user comes back to that page again. As your question is not detailed and I dont know which language you are using on server, its hard to give a complete solution but I can give you an idea (JSP example):

When user presses the `Next` button on page `A` then you will get the selected value in `controller/servlet` and save it in `DB` and move to page `B`

```
String value = request.getAttribute("dropDownValue");
db.saveDropdownValue(value); //just an idea
return "toPageB";
```

When user presses the `Back` button on page `B` then you will get back that saved value from `DB` and return with `request`

```
String savedValue = db.getDropdownValue(); //just an idea
request.setAttribute("savedValue" , savedValue);
return "toPageA";
```

After that just `get` the `request` attribute in your `JSP/View` file

```
<option value="apple" ${'Apple' == param.savedValue ? 'selected' : ''}>Apple</option>
```

Comment: ::  Server its running is APACHE, for UI i`m using the HTML, in the response(HTML) i`m setting the SELECTED value in the options tag, but that`s not reflecting in the browser, in Chrome network log preview,i`m able to see the proper UI as expected,but while inspecting via jquery #(id:selected), for none of the options selected is marked, for everything it marked as false. And also, its working fine if i reload the page. Kindly provide your comments.